# Adjusting context menu font size (MacOS QGIS)

Tags: qgis-3, macos, qswat

After adding QSWAT+ plugin, QGIS fonts (menu, layer names, etc) became very small. I've adjusted the font size under Preference > General > Application > Font

It has worked for most of the menu items but the contextual (right-click) menu is still very small.

I'm using MacBook Pro 16" (Intel).

How can I adjust the font?

Comment: Did you find any solution ? thanks